# Changing the pattern of login url is NOT working

Tags: spring-saml

I am using Spring Security's SAML Extension for authentication and Below works very well, without any issues.

```
<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrentSessionFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter"/>                    
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    <!-- Below Adds an AnonymousAuthenticationFilter to the stack  -->
    <security:anonymous username="roleAnonymous"/>      
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logon/targeturl"
        access="ROLE_CUSTOMER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logon/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/userServlet/unprotected/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/csr/**"
        access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="ROLE_CUSTOMER,ROLE_ADMIN" />  
</security:http>


<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/logon/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/logon/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>            
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/logon/saml/SSO/**" filters="uobSamlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/logon/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/logon/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/logon/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>            
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

But when I change the urls for SAML processing as mentioned below, it does NOT work... any idea, what I am doing wrong? Need is that I want to remove the /logon/ from all the SAML processing urls.

```
<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrentSessionFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter"/>                    
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    <!-- Below Adds an AnonymousAuthenticationFilter to the stack  -->
    <security:anonymous username="roleAnonymous"/>      
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logon/targeturl"
        access="ROLE_CUSTOMER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logon/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />            
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/userServlet/unprotected/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/csr/**"
        access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="ROLE_CUSTOMER,ROLE_ADMIN" />  
</security:http>


<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>            
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="uobSamlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>            
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

When changing the urls you might need to exchange new metadata with the IDP.

To get some more info about what is going on, you can set loglevel to trace for the following packages:

- org.springframework.security.saml
- org.opensaml
- org.springframework.security.web.authentication

Good luck!

:)

Comment: If changing it before the SP meta data has been exchanged then it's not an issue and even updating the SP meta data is not really a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

In recent Spring Security SAML release, you need to set property `filterProcessesUrl` on SAMLEntryPoint